# The value of $0 in .bashrc

Tags: bash, shell

Why the value of $0 in **~/.bashrc** is **bash**?

```
echo "`pwd`/$0 loaded"
```

I expected **/home/thinker3/.bashrc loaded**
but the result:

```
thinker3@ubuntu:~$ source .bashrc
/home/thinker3/bash loaded
```

**My problem was solved, thanks to Michael Hoffman**, I added

```
echo $BASH_SOURCE loaded
```

to ~/.bashrc and /etc/profile, then:

```
/home/thinker3/.bashrc loaded
thinker3@ubuntu:~/addons$ su - root
Password: 
/etc/profile loaded
root@ubuntu:~#
```

Comment: ~/.bashrc does not get executed, but sourced. This means, the process stays the same (`bash`) and no new process is created (`/home/myname/.bashrc`).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Uroc327 points out, `.bashrc` is sourced so `$0` is just the name of the called process (probably `bash`, just as if you echoed `$0` from a command-line). While `.bashrc` is loading, the value of `$BASH_SOURCE` will contain the file's location.

Answer (score 0):

It's `bash`. This can be easily tested by saying

```
echo "$0"
```

in your `.bashrc` and starting a new bash shell.

The reason for this, is that `$0` is the name of the binary that is being run, which is not `.bashrc` but `bash` (usually *resolving* to `/bin/bash` due to the value of `$PATH`).